# Jackson determine derived class

Tags: java, jackson

I have a UseCase where I receive an object via REST and need to determine the concrete type.

The REST controller looks like:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> processLocation(@RequestBody Location location) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

Now `Location` is an empty superclass for two concrete classes, one is `GeoPositionLocation` and the other one is `AdressLocation`.

They look like:

```
public class GeoPositionLocation extends Location{
  private double latitude;
  private double longitude;
}

public class AdressLocation extends Location {
  private String street;
  private int number;
  private String numberAdditive; 
  private int zipCode;
  private String townName;
}
```

Now I want the REST controller to deserialize the passed object to the concrete type.

Things I thought about:

Introduce an Enum and give each class a type and then do a if/else or do two separate REST endpoints for each location type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the annotations `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` like explained in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-polymorphic-type-handling-annotations).

But therefore you would need to serialize the the classes using the same annotations I think. If you can access the serialization of the classes it could look like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = GeoPositionLocation.class, name = "geo_location"), @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AdressLocation.class, name = "adress_location")})
public class Location {
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, thats exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your Location class with

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "profileType", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = GeoPositionLocation.class, name = "homeLocation"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AddressLocation.class, name = "adressLocation")
})
```

and your request should be having an attribute profileType with value as homeLocation or adressLocation based on the concrete class intended. For example a sample AddressLocation request will be like below

```
{
    "street": "My Street",
    "profileType":"adressLocation"

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

So it will deserialize json from message body.

And it will fill only one of 2 your classes if you will give only it so you dont need to separate something

Comment: Jackson is included in Spring, I think you missunderstood the question